# Eliminating Characters using PHP PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre

If I have a string $random, and I want to throw out everything except commas and numbers, how could I do this in PHP PCRE?

I know `\d` will match numbers, but I don't get the rest of PCRE.

Comment: Do you mean commas *within* numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
preg_replace("/[^\d,]/", "", $random);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx) (you don't even need delimiters):

```
pattern('[^\d,]')->remove($random)->all();
```

or if you want only to remove the first

```
pattern('[^\d,]')->remove($random)->first();
```